# Arduino and android eclipse USB communication

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, serial-communication

I want to send data from my arduino mega ADK board to my android app and display this information. I had a lot of trouble with the handler but I got it working. My problem however is not with displaying the information but with the loop of it. Whenever I run my arduino board it keeps on running for about 30 seconds where it keeps on sending data to the app as I can see this in the serial monitor. Then the app displays the received data just once and the serial monitor shows the loop has stopped. I want to continue to see the received information in my android app.
Also note that I made my android app to show me the received data after I pushed a button. However it only displays it once and I cant press the button again to check the display again. (Just stating again I don't want to have to press the button again. It should display the received data continuously after pressing the button once.)

Also, where should the run method actually be called?

Android code:

```
public void run() 
{
    int ret = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
    int i;

    while (true) // read data
    {           
        try 
        {
            ret = mInputStream.read(buffer);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            break;
        }

        i = 0;
        while (i < ret) 
        {
            int len = ret - i;

            if (len >= 1) 
            {
                Message m = Message.obtain(mHandler);
                int value = (int)buffer[i];
                // 'f' is the flag, use for your own logic
                // value is the value from the arduino
                m.obj = new ValueMsg('f', value);
                mHandler.sendMessage(m);
            }

            i += 1; // number of bytes sent from arduino
        }
    }
}

Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public  void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        ValueMsg t = (ValueMsg) msg.obj;
        mResponseField.setText("Flag: "+t.getFlag()+"; Reading: "+t.getReading()+"; Date: "+(new Date().toString()));
    }
};
```

This is where the `run()` method is called:

```
testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
testButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        run();
    }
});
```

This is the Arduino code:

```
#include <CapacitiveSensorDue.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <Max3421e.h>
#include <Usb.h>
#include <AndroidAccessory.h>
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h>

AndroidAccessory acc("Google, Inc.",
    "DemoKit",
    "DemoKit Arduino Board",
    "1.0",
    "http://www.android.com",
    "0000000012345678");

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.print("\r\nStart");
    Serial.print("\r\nStartSetup");
    acc.powerOn();
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.println("\r\nLOOPStart");

    byte msg[1]; // one byte
    char value=10;

    if (acc.isConnected()) {

        while(value>0)
        {
            Serial.print("\r\nawe");// count down
            msg[0] = value;
            acc.write(msg, 1);
            Serial.print(value);
            value-=1;
            delay (1);
        }

        while(value<=10)
        {
            // count up
            msg[0] = value;
            acc.write(msg, 1);
            value+=1;

            delay (1);
        }

        delay (1);
    }
}
```